# webpackJsonp not declared google closure compiler

Tags: webpack, google-closure-compiler

I'm using google's closure compiler with webpack. I have everything setup, but I get an error of `webpackJsonp not declared...` during compilation.

Would love some help.

Comment: Sounds like webpack injects symbols into your build that are defined somewhere else. You can use closure-compiler extern files to tell the compiler these symbols are globals.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are using google/closure-compiler-js? I found it to be more successful on externs.